# Is there any way to avoid the undefined value of key of localStorage.getItem()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

There was the following key pair value in my local storage - instrument,BTX(key,value). I deleted the value manually from local storage. Now the value of this key is undefined.
I have written this condition to avoid the undefined value, but it is not working.
The issue here is that, although the value is undefined so the else block should be executed but here in all possible cases the if block is getting executed.

First way:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("instrument")){}
else {}
```

Second way:

```
if(!!localStorage.getItem("instrument")){}
else {}
```

Third way:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("instrument")!==undefined){}
else {}
```

Comment: You have specified two different ways to determine whether a value is not *falsy*, and one way to check whether it's not undefined. So what's your question?

Comment: Hi @RobbyCornelissen, in all these cases, if block is running, instead else block should run.

Comment: Do you have an empty object in localStorage? You may expect the empty object to be falsy but it is not. `Object.keys(obj).length > 0` can be a check.

Comment: None of your `if` blocks check whether the value is undefined. They all check whether the value is **NOT** undefined/falsy.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Can you please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: The first two checks should be OK, the third isn't as `getItem` returns `null`, not `undefined` if it can't find the key. Are you sure it logs `undefined`? If so, it is the *literal string* `"undefined"` written to it by your code somewhere.

Comment: `if(localStorage.getItem("instrument") || ''){}` use the or trick to set a default value, in this case an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(localStorage.getItem("instrument")!=null){
// Do Something here
}else{
// Do Something Here
}
```

Hope it's working :)